# Include rendered partial view with JsonResult - XSS Injection risk?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views, xss

I needed something like is described here (a method to render a partial view to a string so I can pass it along with some other data as a JsonResult)

[Render a view as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483091/render-a-view-as-a-string/1241257#1241257)

The top answer seems to be working well but I'm wondering if this opens a vector for XSS CSS Injection?

If it does, would it be as easy as html encoding the result before returning it to prevent it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether you are using Json, HTML Partial views, or not the HTTP **POST** actions should
provide some XSS defense. 
Which means The Get was supplied with same token.
Typically in Razor... The token is added,  then checked in POST Action.

```
Html.BeginForm
 @Html.AntiForgeryToken()



 [HttpPost]
 [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
  public AResultTypeHere SomeActionMethod(myModel model)
```

or you use your own hidden field and implement some check.
So Yes, make sure HTTP posts are protected.
http://www.veracode.com/security/xss  as a starter.

There is also MVC based material on the topic, eg 
http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2011/04/28/preventing-javascript-encoding-xss-attacks-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx